# On Feynman's comment about the hydrostatic equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, pressure, density

In *The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Vol. II*, page 515, the author derived the equation describing a fluid in a hydrostatic situation:

$$-\nabla p -\rho \nabla \phi =0,$$

where $p$ is the pressure, $\phi$ is a potential from which the force counterbalancing the pressure force derive (for example, the gravitational potential) , and $\rho$ is the density of the fluid.

He then said, about this equation,

> In general, it has no solution. **If
>   the density varies in space in an arbitrary way, there is no way for the forces to
>   be in balance**, and the fluid cannot be in static equilibrium. Convection currents
>   will start up. We can see this from the equation since the pressure term is a pure
>   gradient, whereas for variable $\rho$ the other term is not. Only when $\rho$ is a constant
>   is the potential term a pure gradient.

Why can't there be a $\phi$ such that $-\rho \nabla \phi$ counterbalances $-\nabla p$ at each point in the fluid?

Why $\rho \nabla \phi$ cannot be a *pure* gradient? I don't really understand what he means by *pure* when referring to these gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\rho = \rho(\mathbf{x})$ and that there exists some potential $\Phi$ such that 
$$ \rho(\mathbf{x}) \nabla \phi = \nabla \Phi.$$

It is well known that the [curl of a gradient is zero:](https://mathinsight.org/curl_gradient_zero)

$$\nabla \times \nabla \Phi = 0,$$ 
so let's calculate this curl explicitly: 
\begin{align}
\nabla \times \nabla \Phi &= \nabla \times [\rho(\mathbf{x}) \nabla \phi]  \\ &= \rho(\mathbf{x}) (\nabla \times \nabla \phi) + \nabla( \rho(\mathbf{x})) \times \nabla\phi \\ &= 0 + \nabla( \rho(\mathbf{x})) \times \nabla\phi.
\end{align}
For an arbitrary $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ we cannot grantee that is has no gradient. Further, if $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ has no gradient then it is (at least locally) [a constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928848/a-function-with-zero-gradient-is-locally-constant). Therefore, a general potential can only exist if $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ is constant, as Feynman states.

Comment: A potential can also exist if $\rho$ is a function of $p$.